# robotframework installed from exe:

Tags: robotframework

I've install robotframework from exe on Windows 7 and now getting error running pybot --version

"C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named robot"

My PYTHONHOME is set to C:\Python27\Scripts
My PYTHONPATH is set to C:\Python27\Lib

Path contains C:\Python27\Scripts

There are following files in C:\Python27\Scripts:

```
ipybot.bat
jybot.bat
pybot.bat
rebot.bat
robot_postinstall.py
robot_postinstall.pyc
robot_postinstall.pyo
```

Answer (score 1):

What exe did you install?  My advice would be to forget what you've done and follow the official installation instructions here:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework/wikis/Installation.wiki

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it's best to append the path of your folder to the PATH variable. 
You can see this more clearly here https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Add the folder path to the PATH variable as said in the instructions above and reset the cmd.